# Abstract factory class returning an interface type, method not found?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, intelephense

I am attempting to use the abstract factory pattern. I've created a class, `FactoryProducer`, that creates a class-specific factory based on a string passed into one of the two class methods.

The issue I'm having is that I've extended one of the concrete factory classes, but the `FactoryProducer` returns an interface type that doesn't include that method. VS Code is saying that the method doesn't exist. Here's the relevant code

**Factory Producer Class**

```
/**
 * Creates database or model factory.
 */
class FactoryProducer {
    /**
     * Creates a factory for the Model classes based on the given function argument.
     *
     * @param string $type The model class (e.g. 'asset', 'employee')
     * @return ModelFactoryInterface The given model's factory.
     */
    public static function getModelFactory(string $type) {
        switch($type) {
            case 'asset':
                return new \Inc\Models\AssetModelFactory;
                break;
            case 'application':
                //code here
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Concrete Factory Class `AssetModelFactory`**

```
/**
 * The factory for the Asset class.
 */
class AssetModelFactory implements ModelFactoryInterface {

    /**
     * Create an empty Asset class object.
     *
     * @return Asset
     */
    function create(): Asset {
        return new Asset();
    }
    /**
     * Creates an Asset object instantiated with the given properties.
     *
     * @param array $props The properties for the class.
     * @return void
     */
    function createWithProps(array $props): Asset {
        $asset = new Asset();
        $keysToCheck = ['name', 'companyName', 'type', 'label', 'location', 'employees', 'key'];
        if(\Inc\Base\Helpers::array_keys_exists($keysToCheck, $props)) {
            $asset->setProperties($props['name'], $props['companyName'], $props['type'], $props['label'], $props['location'], $props['employees'], $props['key']);
            return $asset;
        }
        else {
            return new \WP_Error('incorrect_props', 'You did not include all of the necessary properties.');
        }
        
    }

}
```

The issue I'm having is with the second method, `createWithProps(array $props)`, because the interface doesn't include this method:

```
/**
 * The interface for model classes.
 */
interface ModelFactoryInterface {
    /**
     * Creates an object that extends AbstractModel
     *
     * @return AbstractModel
     */
    public function create(): AbstractModel;
}
```

As you can see, the concrete class objects extend an abstract class. Here is the code that is giving the error:

```
$assetFactory = \Inc\Base\FactoryProducer::getModelFactory('asset');
$asset = $assetFactory->createWithProps($request);
```

I'm wondering if I've implemented the abstract factory class incorrectly, or if this is expected behavior from VS Code given that the returned concrete class from `FactoryProducer` is dynamic based on the parameter (e.g. I've passed 'asset' into the `FactoryProducer::getModelFactory` method which will, ultimately, return an instance of `AssetModelFactory`, but the official return type is `ModelFactoryInterface`).

Thank you in advance for any advice you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out what I did. I am used to programming languages like C# wherein I can strongly-type the variable prior to declaring it. I ended up refactoring the code so that the factories have methods that return a specific concrete object instead of using a switch statement:

```
class DBFactory implements DBFactoryInterface  {

    public static function createAsset(): AbstractDB { 
        return new \Inc\DB\AssetDB;
    }

    public static function createApplication(): AbstractDB { 
        return new \Inc\DB\ApplicationDB;
    }

    public static function createCompany(): AbstractDB { 
        return new \Inc\DB\CompanyDB;
    }
}
```